# Possible to Combine Class with Executable Script?

Tags: python

Is it possible to combine a class along with an executable script in a single file?

i.e. see the code below:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def main():
    try:
        execute_app()
    finally:
        handle_cleanup()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Person.main()
```

and, if it is possible, what are its merits?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it makes your code harder to read. Don't do it.

Comment: Doesn't really make the code harder to read…just harder to understand. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You should put your classes and libraries (functions) in another source file, then call them on your script. This makes your code easier to read.

Comment: Noted. Thanks to all